# How can I group by one column to join values in multiple rows?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

Let's say I have a survey of people in teams, and what fruits they like:

```
User  | Team  | Fruits
----------------------
Dave  | Mine  | Banana, Apple
Steve | Mine  | Apple, Orange
Matt  | Yours | Banana
```

This would have been populated by a Google Form. I am looking to transform this into:

```
Team  | Fruits
--------------
Mine  | Banana, Apple, Orange
Yours | Banana
```

I'd then be able to know that two teams like bananas, while one team also likes apples and oranges. I have been looking into some combination of QUERY and JOIN but am getting pretty lost.

In one cell, I have done `=UNIQUE('Raw Responses'!C2:C105)`, which gets me all the unique Teams.

In another, I've done `=JOIN(", ",'Raw Responses'!E2, 'Raw Responses'!E3)` gets me what I want manually (without the unique values bit yet, so I would see apples twice).

In my third test, I did `=QUERY('Raw Responses'!C2:E105, "SELECT E where C='Mine'")`, which spreads the answer across two rows

Note that `C` corresponds to `Teams` and `E` corresponds to `Fruits` in my actual sheet.

**Update**

`=JOIN(", ", QUERY('Raw Responses'!C2:E105, "SELECT E where C='Mine'"))` almost is what I want. I am just not sure how to make `Mine` become a pointer of `A1` inside a different sheet than `Raw Responses` as this is in `Sheet2`. I then need to make the cell be unique values only still.

**Update 2**
`=JOIN(", ", QUERY('Raw Responses'!C2:E105, "SELECT E where C='" & $A1 & "'"))` is working, just need to figure out unique values now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=JOIN(", ", UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(", ", QUERY('Raw Responses'!$C2:$BP105, "SELECT F where C='" & $A2 & "'")), ", "))))` solves it.

It basically transforms between columns and rows so I can use unique and then slap it all back.

Answer (score 0):

- **`JOIN`** formula will fail on joining more than 50000 characters, so here is the backup for that:

  - cell **E2**: **`=UNIQUE(B2:B)`**
  - cell **F2** and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN($B$2:$B), "♦"&$B$2:$B&"♠"&
 IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT($C$2:$C, ",")), $C$2:$C), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♦")), "♠")), " ", "♥")), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = '"&E2&"' and Col2 is not null", 0), , 999^99), " ", ", "), "♥", " "))
```

[image: 0]